# Unable to resolve the request "site/error"

Tags: php, yii

I am new to the PHP Yii framework. I just started a project. I installed Yii and put my `sitecontroller.php` into an admin folder. When I run the url, this bug is displayed:

```
Unable to resolve the request "site/error". (C:\wamp\www\foldername\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:286)

#0 C:\wamp\www\foldername\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(331): CWebApplication->runController('site/error')
#1 C:\wamp\www\foldername\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(204): CErrorHandler->render('error', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\foldername\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(129): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
#3 C:\wamp\www\foldername\framework\base\CApplication.php(732): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#4 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
#5 {main}
```

Comment: Clean up the tags. Leave just php and yii. Java and phpmyadmin have nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the application first instead of plainly putting the controller code into the folder.

Starting to work with Yii is a bit different in this matter, than, for example, with codeigniter, where you can put the controller into admin folder and just enjoy the show.

Do this to generate the app:

```
% cd WebRoot/testdrive
% php YiiRoot/framework/yiic.php webapp WebRoot/testdrive
```

Here is a [whole tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.0/en/quickstart.first-app).

After you build your sample app, modify it to suit your needs.

It would be rather hard to manually add files until you are comfortable with yii architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is yii1 not yii2, sitecontroller.php should be SiteController.php. It is case sensitive.